# Combining SELECTs and filtering by a column in a different table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. The first stores `orders`:

```
id | date | status
```

The second table stores `revisions` (changes to orders):

```
name | date | product | producer | etc...
```

I am displaying orders with this query:

```
SELECT id, date from orders
```

Then I'm displaying only the last revision to each order with this query:

```
SELECT name, product, producer from revisions WHERE order_id = id ORDER BY date LIMIT 1
```

Two questions:

- How can I combine these into a single `SELECT`?
- How can I filter all orders by there `name` in the `revisions` table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html):

```
SELECT o.id, o.date,
       r.name, r.product, r.producer
FROM   orders o JOIN (revisions r NATURAL JOIN (
         SELECT   order_id, name, MAX(date) date
         FROM     revisions
         WHERE    name = ?
         GROUP BY order_id
       ) t) ON r.order_id = o.id
```

Note that if multiple revisions of a single order have the same value for `revisions.date`, then they will all be returned in the results (whereas your previous approach with `LIMIT 1` would have returned an indeterminate one).  If you want to be more selective, you need to decide the criteria for choosing which result to select.